# Sql query mistake for the weekly statistics

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a weekly statistics for user registration. It should work for weekly. There are total of seven days in a week. I want to print the number of users who are registered every day in the week on the screen.

For example:

> Number of users who registered on Monday = 38
>
> Number of users who registered on Tuesday = 11
>
> .... .... **and this list will only list the week we were**

I created a sql query like the following:

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(registerTime)+1, count(*) 
FROM users group by WEEKDAY(registerTime) 
ORDER BY WEEKDAY(registerTime)
```

But the outcome of this question is very different. This total shows the number of users who registered on Monday for every year .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to limit users to only this week so you don't get everything:

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(registerTime)+1, count(*) 
FROM users
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(registerTime) = WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE()) 
     AND YEAR(registerTime) = YEAR(CURDATE())
group by WEEKDAY(registerTime)
ORDER BY WEEKDAY(registerTime);
```

Basically you match the year and week of year with what you need. That should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Php` code for this purpose. First make array of days and then you can get registered users for each day through that `array`

```
function today()
{
    return date("Y-m-d");

}
function last_seventh_day()
{
    return date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-7 days"));

}

$days = ['Saturday','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'];//Array that stores all days



foreach($days as $day)
    {
        $sql = "select * FROM users where day = '$day'  and date_column between " .today() . "and" .last_seventh_day() ;
    }
```

I have updated my answer. I hope this will work for you!

Comment: I want to print weekly within one query,  not all single day

Comment: All single day of particular week?

Comment: We are in the first week of March and i want to show: This week registered user 21 on Monday, 11 on Tuesday, 34 on Wednesday, 55 on Thursday, 32 on Friday and 8 on Saturday.

Comment: i just need sql query so thank you so much for your good answer also but apokryfos fined solution with sql query.

Comment: Ok, Thats nice... Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
SELECT datepart(week, registerTime), count(*) FROM Users GROUP BY datepart(week, registerTime)
```

Comment: Please let me know exactly what output would you want?

Comment: @apokryfos understood what i want